# Eigenvectors for spin matrix along arbitrary direction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, linear-algebra

In Appendix A of [this paper](https://www.physics.wisc.edu/courses/home/spring2020/407/experiments/bell/Bell%27s%20Theorem%20Background%20Papers/Greenberger_Bell_without_inequalities_Am.J.P.58.1131.pdf), the authors start from (equ. A1a and A1b)

$$\sigma \cdot \hat{n} |\hat{n},+\rangle = |\hat{n},+\rangle $$
$$\sigma \cdot \hat{n} |\hat{n},-\rangle = -|\hat{n},-\rangle $$

and claim that this system of linear equations is solved by (A2a and A2b):

$$|\hat{n},+\rangle = \cos(\frac{\theta}{2})e^{-i\phi/2}|+\rangle+\sin(\frac{\theta}{2})e^{i\phi/2}|-\rangle$$
$$|\hat{n},-\rangle = -\sin(\frac{\theta}{2})e^{-i\phi/2} |+\rangle + \cos(\frac{\theta}{2})e^{i\phi/2}|-\rangle$$

I do not get how they did this. In order to solve it by myself I assumed that what they meant by $\sigma \cdot \hat{n}$ was:
$$\sigma \cdot \hat{n} = \begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\phi) & \sin(\phi)e^{-i\theta} \\
\sin(\phi)e^{i\theta} & -\cos(\phi)
\end{bmatrix}$$
as e.g. shown in the answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/88368/how-do-i-measure-the-spin-along-an-arbitrary-direction). Therefore $|\hat{n},+\rangle$ and $|\hat{n},-\rangle$ should simply be the eigenvectors of this matrix. I computed the eigenvectors [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eigenvector%20calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22Eigenvector%22%2C%20%22eigvecmatrix%22%7D%20-%3E%22%7B%7Bcos%28a%29%2C%20sin%28a%29*exp%28-i*b%29%7D%2C%7Bsin%28a%29*exp%28i*b%29%2C%20-cos%28a%29%7D%7D%22), but this does not yield the same result as in the paper cited above (I tried trigonometric identities but this led me nowhere). As far as I understood $|+\rangle$ and $|-\rangle$ are supposed to be the eigenvectors of the Pauli matrix $\sigma_z$, since they are ''*states of spin-up and -down along a specified direction, commonly $\hat{z}$*''. [i.e. the vectors are supposed to be $|+\rangle = (1,0)$ and $|-\rangle = (0,1)$, which is the basis of the matrix I assumed above. Therefore I don't see where my error can be found.]

What did I do wrong? How can I derive $|\hat{n},+\rangle$ and $|\hat{n},-\rangle$ correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that your $\vec{\sigma}\cdot\hat{n}$ indicates that you are using $\phi$ for the polar angle and $\theta$ for the azimuthal one, while in the solution it is defined the opposite way.

Then, some hints:

1. Using trigonometric identities you can get

$$\cot\phi-\csc\phi=\frac{\cos\phi-1}{\sin\phi}=-\frac{2}{\sin\phi}\frac{1-\cos\phi}{2}=-\frac{2}{2\sin\left(\frac{\phi}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\phi}{2}\right)}\sin^2\left(\frac{\phi}{2}\right)=-\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\phi}{2}\right)}{\cos\left(\frac{\phi}{2}\right)}$$

and

$$\cot\phi+\csc\phi=\frac{\cos\phi+1}{\sin\phi}=\frac{2}{\sin\phi}\frac{1+\cos\phi}{2}=\frac{2}{2\sin\left(\frac{\phi}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\phi}{2}\right)}\cos^2\left(\frac{\phi}{2}\right)=\frac{\cos\left(\frac{\phi}{2}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{\phi}{2}\right)}$$

2. The eigenvectors must be normalized.
3. You can multiply a vector by a gobal phase $e^{i\gamma}$.

I think you should be able to get the result with this, and don't forget the issue with the definition of angles!